# Name Servers changed over 48 hrs ago and site is still down

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy

Ok, I just recently changed Name Servers for my site (Oct. 29th):  http://dream-portal.net but there is an issue, the name servers were changed from godaddy, however, the DNS is being hosted elsewhere.  Godaddy states that the DNS is resolving the site to www.dream-portal.net and that is making it inaccessible from the DNS on the other host and that they can't do anything because I'm not hosting DNS with godaddy.

I've contacted the other host and they say that everything is fine, however, people are not able to access the site and I can't access it from my work computer.  I can only access it from my home computer.  From my work computer it says that the page can not be found.

What should I do?  What can I do?

Other people reported problems with the site here:  http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=487592.msg3629960#msg3629960

Comment: Everything checks out; your DNS seems fine and your web site comes up correctly.

Comment: Godaddy Domain Diagnostics says that their is a problem with the name servers though and that some people may not be able to access the site.  Also, godaddy said that they themselves are not able to access my site at http://dream-portal.net and that it reports "Page Not Found"

Comment: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.dream-portal.net shows that you do indeed have a problem.

Comment: Site comes up fine here.

Comment: You have internet dudes running your name servers. They can say any old thing about nothing being wrong, but I cannot resolve NS1 through NS4 at xarpixels.com. No name server resolution, no web server resolution. The root servers cannot find your xarpixels.com dudes according to dig.

Comment: @Skyhawk Worst case of propagation I've ever seen, Beijing and Paris now show name resolution.

Comment: @FiascoLabs - Does that mean it is still propagating?

Comment: No, it appears to be stuck in limbo with limited numbers of servers being able to resolve your name servers. I've tried several different dig utilities using different main hosts and have had only one able to resolve an IP address for your name servers. Most just come up NXDOMAIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who maintains the name server? Is that you or another company?

At GoDaddy you have two settings:

**1. Nameservers**

That's easy, something such as ns1.dream-portal.net and ns2.dream-portal.net

If those are from another company, you should be all good. If you are running your own name server, then you also need to setup the **Host Names**.

**2. Host Names**

This is the IP addresses for the ns1 and ns2 name servers. This is required if you host your own nameserver.

---

Now, I checked your whois and it shows the name server as: NS1.XARPIXELS.COM

If I run dig against it, it says it doesn't know anything about your domain:

```
> dig @NS1.XARPIXELS.COM dream-portal.net
dig: couldn't get address for 'NS1.XARPIXELS.COM': failure
```

So the setup at XarPixels.com is wrong. Without that, what still works comes from caches. Notice the @<nameserver> syntax to very that this very nameserver is properly setup.

Comment: ns1 through ns4 for xarpixels.com are DOA, no ip address resolution. For some reason, the ip address is stuck in the name resolution I use, will probably expire out soon and the site will totally disappear. Name: dream-portal.net Address: 192.65.243.61 -> Name: cronus-dal.thewebhostserver.com Address: 192.65.243.61

Comment: cronus-dal.thewebhostserver.com is the PTR of that IP address. You need the PTR to send emails and if you accept credit cards. Otherwise it's not too important. But if ns1.xarpixels.com cannot be resolved, then you should not use that name in your GoDaddy settings. Instead, directly specify the IP addresses for ns1 & ns2...

Comment: Nameservers are set within godaddy, but I don't control anything else besides name servers on godaddy, xarpixels.com controls the rest of it all.  So, I'm assuming that the problem lies with XarPixels than?  This was my original thought, but they say that everything is fine on their end of things.  I don't have any IP on NS1, or NS2 set.

Comment: Bad case of "Dude, where's my name server?" The name servers are unreachable and unresolvable, you need them to prove that the root servers can find the name servers, which they can't.

Comment: As Fiasco mentioned, the name servers need to be accessible. If you are using a GoDaddy nameserver, then put the GoDaddy nameserver in your domain settings. XarPixels does not exist it seems... (or you got the name wrong.)

Comment: No, I got the name right.  The host told me to remove NS3.XARPIXELS.COM and NS4.XARPIXELS.COM and so I did this about 3 hours ago, and does this mean that I have to wait another 48 hours for NS1.XARPIXELS.COM and NS2.XARPIXELS.COM to fully propagate again?  Are you sure that these name servers do not exist?  How can you be sure?  Especially when Skyhawk pointed out that it seems to work in some areas with the whatsmydns url, but not all.  I do not have a Godaddy name server to use.

Comment: We can be sure because dig traces show the routing from the root servers attempting to direct us to XARPIXELS.COM and majorly failing to get an answer. We can use dig to try to resolve the name servers to get their IP addresses, which fails. I can go do the same things on my live ecommerce site and immediately find my server ip and all three name server IPs. Out of all the name servers I plugged in for dig, only one actually resolved anything. Root Servers can't find you, only one oddball out there responds. Especially when Skyhawk pointed out that out _you do indeed have a problem_.

Comment: Thanks Fiasco!  Really appreciate this!  Marked this as the answer and told the host this.  So if it isn't resolved shortly, I will be switching my hosting to godaddy I guess.

Comment: Problem is resolved now!  Thanks so much guys for looking into this.  There was no A Record added to the name servers!  UNBELIEVABLE!

Comment: Wow, all the difference in the world! Everyone knows your IP except Beijing occasionally due to the Great Firewall. Glad to help!